# Объект без встроенных методов Ruby – как такое возможно?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Тестирую тут Rails-проект, а сегодня тесты вдруг поломались, и в процессе копаний обнаружил вот такой вот странный объект:

```
(byebug) BaseMailer::AdminMailer.delay
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `:inspect' for "BaseMailer::AdminMailer":String

(byebug) BaseMailer::AdminMailer.delay.is_a?(String)
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `:is_a?' for "BaseMailer::AdminMailer":String

nil
(byebug) BaseMailer::AdminMailer.delay.respond_to?(:is_a?)
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `:respond_to?' for "BaseMailer::AdminMailer":String

nil
(byebug) BaseMailer::AdminMailer.delay.nil?
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `:nil?' for "BaseMailer::AdminMailer":String

nil
(byebug) wtfobj = BaseMailer::AdminMailer.delay
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `:inspect' for "BaseMailer::AdminMailer":String

(byebug) wtfobj.nil?
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `:nil?' for "BaseMailer::AdminMailer":String
```

Как видно, он не отвечает ни на один из методов, которые я до сих пор видел у абсолютно любого объекта:

```
irb(main):001:0> nil.nil?
=> true
irb(main):002:0> nil.respond_to?(:is_a?)
=> true
irb(main):003:0> Object.nil?
=> false
```

Спрашивать, как это починить, я не стану: оно сломалось только в одной ветке проекта и сломалось недавно, как-нибудь уж сам разберусь, вооружившись диффом (но подозрения падают на поломанный Sidekiq, если вдруг кому-то интересно) *(UPD: а ещё SafeYAML влияет, оказывается)*. Меня сейчас интересует другое.

Как такой объект вообще возможно создать?

Comment: bug в byebug...

Comment: Кстати, для чистоты эксперимента нужно было бы выполнить Object.new.nil? т.к. Object принадлежит классу Class

Comment: @anoam таки `false`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Отвечая на вопрос "как можно создать объект без встроенных Ruby методов" - http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/BasicObject.html

```
irb(main):001:0> class A < BasicObject; end
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> A.new
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
=> 
irb(main):003:0> A.new.nil?
NoMethodError: undefined method `nil?' for #<A:0x007fdb0e936638>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если чуть внимательнее посмотреть, то становится понятным что там вызываются не стандартные `inspect`, `is_a?`, и прочие, а какие-то странные: `:inspect`, `:is_a?`
Единственный способ как сделать такое я вижу в том, что неаккуратно переводили константы из `Symbol` в сторку:

```
 > obj = :foo
 > obj.foo
 => NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for :foo:Symbol
 > obj.send :foo
 => undefined method `foo' for :foo:Symbol
 > obj.:foo
 => syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting '('
 > obj.send ":foo"
 => undefined method `:foo' for :foo:Symbol
```